# $\operatorname{Out}(S_7)=1$ at work.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let's suppose that $\operatorname{Out}(S_{n\ne 6})=1$ is not a known result. Let's denote with $\mathcal{C}_{(i_1,\dots,i_k)}$ the conjugacy class of $S_7$ corresponding to the cycle type $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ (whence $i_1+\dots+i_k=7$). It turns out that:

$$\#\mathcal{C}_{(1,1,1,2,2)}=\#\mathcal{C}_{(1,2,2,2)}(=105)\tag 1$$

So, in principle, there could be a non-inner automorphism of $S_7$, say $\varphi$, such that:

$$\varphi(\mathcal{C}_{(1,1,1,2,2)})=\mathcal{C}_{(1,2,2,2)}\tag 2$$

What does actually prevent the existence of such a $\varphi$?

Comment: The fact that it *still* has to preserve transpositions ie permutations of type $(1,1,1,1,1,2)$?

Comment: @Mindlack, do you mean that $\varphi((ij)(kl))=\varphi((ij))\varphi((kl))=(mn)(pq)$, and the latter term can't  be an element of $\mathcal{C}_{(1,2,2,2)}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.